# How to write and || (or) and a && (and) within the same IF statement

Tags: apex

```
 if(Opp.Term__c != 'Sale' && ((Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') || (Opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost'))) Opp.Date_Closed__c = system.today();
```

Doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Except for some additional parentheses, your condition should still evaluate if your records contain the data that you expect here. You should instead verify if your record evaluates to your condition. And also try to reformat the if condition by removing those extra parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine, but note that your parentheses are slightly overkill:

```
if(Opp.Term__c != 'Sale' && (Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' || Opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost')) {
  Opp.Date_Closed__c = system.today(); 
}
```

As a side note, always use `{}` around your if statement's true/false paths; it's too easy to accidentally assume that the next statement is part of the if/else if you forget to do this. You should always do this, even if it's a single-line statement.